# passing varargin to subfunction if string

Tags: matlab, function, arguments, variadic-functions

I want to modify function rand and define my own function

```
function num = rand(varargin)
```

Most of the time, i just wrap the invocation

```
num = builtin("rand", [varargin{:}]);
```

and this works well except in case there is a string argument.

For `rand(2,3,"double")` I obtain

```
warning: implicit conversion from numeric to char
warning: called from rand at line 83 column 11
error: rand: unrecognized string argument
error: called from rand at line 83 column 11
```

and for `rand("seed",2)` the same.

ON the other hand, `rand("seed")` seems to work fine.

Can anyone offer an explanation and a solution?

Comment: `num = builtin('rand', varargin{:});` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax:

```
num = builtin('rand', [varargin{:}]);
```

Will only work for you in cases where the input arguments can be represented as either a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) or a vector, such as when you specify a size for `rand`:

```
num = rand(2, 3, 4);
% Or ...
num = rand([2 3 4]);
```

It **will not** work for inputs that must be entered separately, like so:

```
num = rand(2, 3, 'double');  % Works
num = rand([2 3 'double']);  % Throws an error
```

In general, you should just pass the contents of [`varargin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html) as a comma-separated list (without [collecting the contents into a vector/matrix](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/horzcat.html)) since [`builtin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/builtin.html) is designed to handle that just fine:

```
num = builtin('rand', varargin{:});
```

Also, be mindful of the difference between "strings" like `'rand'` (a [character array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-character-arrays.html)) and `"rand"` (a [string](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-string-arrays.html)). They can have different behavior in certain cases.